# ODBC command. How to pass parameter for LIMIT operand

Tags: c#, odbc, limit

Here is the code for query:

```
using (var connection = Connection) {
                string commandText;
                OdbcCommand command;
                if (loadedNodes.Count > 0)
                {
                    commandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where (PAR_1 = ? OR PAR_2 = ?) and PAR_1 NOT IN ({0}) and PAR_2 NOT IN ({0}) LIMIT ?";
                    var paramNames = loadedNodes.Select((s, index) => $"'@param{index}'").ToArray();
                    var inClause = string.Join(", ", paramNames);
                    command = new OdbcCommand(string.Format(commandText, inClause), connection);
                    for (int i = 0; i < paramNames.Length; i++)
                    {
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramNames[i], loadedNodes[i]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    commandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where (PAR_1 = ? OR PAR_2 = ?) LIMIT ?";
                    command = new OdbcCommand(commandText, connection);
                }

                command.Parameters.Add("@PAR_1", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = inn;
                command.Parameters.Add("@PAR_2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = inn;
                command.Parameters.Add("", OdbcType.Int).Value = limit;//!!!

                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        relatedRegistries.Add(Mapper.Resolve().Map<NdsRegistry>(reader));
                    }
                }
            }
```

In the first case when I am passing the limit param using `""` - works fine.

In the second case `commandText` from `command` object looks like:

> `SELECT * FROM TABLENAME where (PAR_1 = ? OR PAR_2 = ?) and PAR_1 NOT IN ('@param0') and PAR_2 NOT IN ('@param0') LIMIT ?`

And I am getting error telling that:

```
 ERROR [HY000] [Hortonworks][Phoenix] (2020) An error occured while executing statement: 
    8org.apache.calcite.avatica.proto.Responses$ErrorResponse‘
    ћjava.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.phoenix.schema.TypeMismatchException: ERROR 203 (22005): Type mismatch. INTEGER and VARCHAR
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.jdbc.JdbcMeta.propagate(JdbcMeta.java:683)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.jdbc.JdbcMeta.execute(JdbcMeta.java:878)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.LocalService.apply(LocalService.java:268)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$ExecuteRequest.accept(Service.java:1026)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.Service$ExecuteRequest.accept(Service.java:1002)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.AbstractHandler.apply(AbstractHandler.java:94)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.remote.ProtobufHandler.apply(ProtobufHandler.java:46)
        at org.apache.calcite.avatica.server.AvaticaProtobufHandler.handle(AvaticaProtobufHandler.java:127)
        at org.apache.phoenix.shaded.org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle...
```

Can anybody please suggest, what's the proper way to pass parameter into odbc command without `=` sign?

Comment: Probably depends on the underlying data storage engine

Comment: It's Apache Phoenix. Or the question is not about it ?